# Split the string in C++ using command std::string::substr

Tags: c++, string, split

I'm able to get the first half of string:

```
 insert1 = tCreatureOne.substr(0, (tCreatureOne.length) / 2
```

I don't know how to get the second half of the string

```
insert2 = tCreatureOne.substr((tCreatureOne.length) / 2), ?????)
```

Here is my code.

```
// Insert creature two in to the
//middle of creature one.Science!
// Hamster and Emu make a HamEmuster

std::string PerformScience(std::string tCreatureOne, std::string tCreatureTwo)

{

    std::string insert1;
    std::string insert2;
    std::string insert3;


        // first half : 0 to middle

        insert1 = tCreatureOne.substr(0, (tCreatureOne.length) / 2); 

    // last half: from middle to the end
        insert2 = tCreatureOne.substr((tCreatureOne.length) / 2), tCreatureOne.length); 

        insert3 = insert1 + tCreatureTwo + insert2;

    return insert3;
```

Comment: You can't without calling `substr()` again! Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c) out.

Comment: From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/ I suspect you're looking for `string::npos`. I.e. `insert2 = tCreatureOne.substr((tCreatureOne.length) / 2), std::string::npos);`

Comment: @CraigYoung `std::string::npos` is already the default. It's not necessary to specify the 2nd parameter at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the most important developer skill is knowing how to do online research. A google search for "c++ substr" reveals this as the top result: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

In the section describing parameters, `len` is described as follows:

> Number of characters to include in the substring (if the string is shorter, as many characters as possible are used).
>   **A value of string::npos indicates all characters until the end of the string.**

So you could write:

```
insert2 = tCreatureOne.substr(tCreatureOne.length() / 2), std::string::npos);
```

However, note that `substr` is declared as follows:

> `string substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;`

Meaning `len` quite conveniently defaults to `npos`.
Therefore you could more simply write:

```
insert2 = tCreatureOne.substr(tCreatureOne.length() / 2));
```

However, even if `substr` didn't have such a convenient means of specifying 'the rest of the string', you could still have quite easily calculated it as follows:

```
int totalLength = tCreatureOne.length();
int firstLength = totalLength / 2;
int remainderLength = totalLength - firstLength;

//So...
insert2 = tCreatureOne.substr(tCreatureOne.length() / 2), remainderLength);
```

Comment: I made a mistake. I should write  tCreatureOne.length() instead of tCreatureOne.length
thank you for your help, ur answer really helped me understand everything about substring command and help finished my hw on time

Answer (score 0):

πάντα ῥεῖ is correct in their comment - to retrieve the second half of your string, you don't need to specify a second parameter (the end of the string):

```
insert2 = tCreatureOne.substr(tCreatureOne.length() / 2);
```

The line above will work perfectly fine. Also, since you're using `std::string`, remember to add the parentheses to the `length()` call.